# NavigationBar tintColor not affecting textcolor

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made a subclass for UINavigationController where i change the colors of the bar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [StyleKit2 blue];
    self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

The barTintColor is changed to blue, but the Title text is not changed to white. TintColor should affect all the items in the bar?

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tintColor` is used to tint of the navigation bar items, the `barTintColor` is used to tint the background, but in order to tint the title, you have to use `setTitleTextAttributes`.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [StyleKit2 blue];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar 
 setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

More information about it:

- [UINavigationBar class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes)